# Changing a posts picture depending on the category in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am working in the Reventon theme, and I am in the file post.php.

On the blog page, there is an image that is spit out on the left side of every post. I am trying to change that picture depending on what category is assigned to the post.

I have tried using this so far:

```
if (is_category('video')) {
        ?>
            <div class="post-format-icon rectangle-shadow">
                <i class="icon-entypo-play-align-left"></i>
            </div>
        <?php
    } elseif (is_category('Podcast')) {
        ?>
            <div class="post-format-icon rectangle-shadow">
                <i class="icon-entypo-rss-align-left"></i>
            </div>
        <?php
    } else {
        ?>
            <div class="post-format-icon rectangle-shadow">
                <i class="icon-symbol-align-left"></i>
            </div>
        <?php
    }
```

but for some reason it keeps triggering the ending else statement and not giving the unique picture depending on the category.. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your output for the last two statements is exactly the same.

Comment: Woops--made a mistake and grabbed an older version.. Updated @HeikkiU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `in_category( 'category_name' )` instead of `is_category()`. The latter is for checking if a category archive page is being displayed, not the category of a post. Have a look at [The WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category).